# apache2 reverse proxy with domain

Tags: proxy, apache2, reverse-proxy

I'm not sure if it's possible what I'm trying to do but I have a few applications on multiple servers. I have one server for gitlab, one for jenkins and one for sonarqube. I want to be able to navigate to them by using my domain as follows:

```
gitlab > https:// git.mydomain.com
jenkins > https:// jenkins.mydomain.com
sonarqube > http:// sonar.mydomain.com
```

What I'm trying to do is setup a reverse proxy with apache2 on a 4th server that runs independent from the applications. Here is what I tried to do:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName http:// mydomain.com
    ProxyPass http:// sonar.mydomain.com/ http:// sonar.mydomain.com:9000/
    ProxyPassReverse http:// sonar.mydomain.com http:// sonar.mydomain.com:9000/
    ProxyPass http:// jenkins.mydomain.com/ https:// jenkins.mydomain.com:8081/
    ProxyPassReverse http:// jenkins.mydomain.com/ https:// jenkins.mydomain.com:8081/
</VirtualHost>
```

When I do it this way it won't work it will just go to the apache default page. What I did try is doing it with / and I noticed that it won't work with https:// extentions no matter in what way I try to set it. Is there a way to get this working?

and is it possible to set the proxy up the way I want?

Answer (score 1):

Just create three name-based virtualhosts and use "/" as the first parameter for ProxyPass.    Each vhost proxies to the corrsponding app.